# Visual Fields testing: Decibels of sensitivity - meaning

Tags: visible-light, vision, medical-physics

Automated Visual Field test measures the patient light sensitivity in decibels.

Questions:

If one point has sensitivity of 30 decibels and another point has sensitivity of 27 decibels does it mean that point 1 is 2 times more sensitive than point 2?

If point 3 has sensitivity of 31dB and point 4 has 21dB does it mean that point 3 sensitivity is 10 times greater than of point4?

Third and most important question - How these decibels calculated mathematically? Is there way to reconstruct this (theoretical) calculation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel How they are calculated depends on the reference value.

Comment: @user6972 I am looking for the info HOW they calculated the value :)

Comment: We can't tell you exactly because we don't know what their reference is.  Decibels are exponents values based on a ratio to a reference. 1V, 1W, 1mW...etc.  I found a little calculator for you once you find out how your systems reference the measurements http://www.rapidtables.com/electric/decibel.htm

Comment: @user6972 there is something that I dont understand even I have sufficient data. Let's say the maximum of the testing machine is 100(some units) and it give stimuli of -10 step - from here can I calculate the decibels?

Comment: without knowing what reference number was used to compute the dB, then you can't know for sure how to convert back.  Call the manufacturer.

Comment: @user6972 I know the exact reference number - "The Humphrey perimeters adopted the traditional Goldmann level of background illumination (31.5 asb); thus they produce a maximum stimulus of 10 000 asb." from Here https://www.inkling.com/read/stein-ophthalmic-assistant-9th/chapter-18/units-of-measure. I am not able to reconstruct the maths though, this is why I ask someone here to help me with the calculations

Comment: Because that's probably not the reference.  Most likely it is 1 asb or perhaps 10 asb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just guessing on this based on the reference you posted in the comments.  Sometimes dB's are referenced to a max level, like with audio at 120dB.  In this case they look at the difference between the maximum.

In your case, 10,000 is the max, or 40 dB.  Based on this scale comparison:

[image: comparison]

I would guess apostilibs to dB is done like this:

$dB = 40 - 10*log(apostilibs)$

And the other way would be
$apostilbs = 10^{(4-dB_{value}/10)}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I thought that in the place of "log(apostilibs)" should be division operator, like Aps1/Aps2... what do I miss?

Comment: Based on the scale you posted it appears the reference is Abs2=1 abs.